# Putting purple color to MATLAB font and code structure

Tags: listings, matlab

I have this MATLAB code:

[image]

After sysms the variables turn purple and I cannot make that in the MATLAB script I have in Latex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bigfoot} % to allow verbatim in footnote
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier} 

\begin{filecontents*}{sample.m} 
%Parcial Computacion Cientifica (Punto 1) 
%Solucion del sistema de Ecuaciones para a2 y a3   

%Se definen los variables simbolicas del sistema.
syms h a2 a3 f0 df0 f1 df1


eqn1 = f0 + df0*h + a2*(h^2) + a3*(h^3) == f1; %Ecuacion 7
eqn2 = df0 + 2*a2*h + 3*a3*(h^2) == df1; %Ecuacion 9  

%Solucion del sistema de Ecuaciones.
solution = solve([eqn1, eqn2],[a2 a3]); 

a2 = solution.a2; %Solucion de a2 
a3 = solution.a3; %Solucion de a3

\end{filecontents*}  

\let\ph\mlplaceholder % shorter macro
\lstMakeShortInline"

\lstset{
  style              = Matlab-editor,
  basicstyle         = \mlttfamily,
  escapechar         = ",
  mlshowsectionrules = true,
}

\lstinputlisting[caption = {Sample code from Matlab}]{sample.m}
```

[image]

If someone could tell me how to turn any of text to purple MATLAB-like it could be really helpful, also I would like to know how to  make the number of lines and the font of the code look like this:

[image]

Comment: Yes that's exactly the answer, thank you. Do you have any idea of how to correct the format part?

Comment: Yes :) see the update to the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add `mlunquotedstringdelim` to the `lstset` declarations, providing two delimiters of your liking (I used `§`).

```
\lstset{
  style              = Matlab-editor,
  basicstyle         = \mlttfamily,
  escapechar         = ",
  mlshowsectionrules = true,
  mlunquotedstringdelim={§}{§},
}
```

To have the numbers inside the frame, as per your second screenshot, just add `xleftmargin=2em,framexleftmargin=2.5em,`, and increase the margin according to your taste ;)
The resulting MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bigfoot} % to allow verbatim in footnote
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{filecontents}{sample.m}
%Parcial Computacion Cientifica (Punto 1)
%Solucion del sistema de Ecuaciones para a2 y a3

%Se definen los variables simbolicas del sistema.
syms §h a2 a3 f0 df0 f1 df1§


eqn1 = f0 + df0*h + a2*(h^2) + a3*(h^3) == f1; %Ecuacion 7
eqn2 = df0 + 2*a2*h + 3*a3*(h^2) == df1; %Ecuacion 9

%Solucion del sistema de Ecuaciones.
solution = solve([eqn1, eqn2],[a2 a3]);

a2 = solution.a2; %Solucion de a2
a3 = solution.a3; %Solucion de a3

\end{filecontents}

\let\ph\mlplaceholder % shorter macro
\lstMakeShortInline"

\lstset{
    style                 = Matlab-editor,
    basicstyle            = \mlttfamily,
    escapechar            = ",
    mlshowsectionrules    = true,
    mlunquotedstringdelim = {§}{§},
    xleftmargin           = 2em,
    framexleftmargin      = 2.5em
}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[caption = {Sample code from Matlab}]{sample.m}

\end{document}
```

[image]